# Insufficient Privileges on apex:selectList onchange

Tags: visualforce

I am getting above error onchange of a selectList. Debug console does not show anything.

selectList is populated in following way:

```
 for(String fieldName : optionStrings){
            Schema.SObjectField sfield = mapField.get(fieldname);
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult descResField = sfield.getDescribe();
            String fieldLabel = descResField.getLabel();
            userOptions.add(new         SelectOption(descResField.getLocalName(),fieldLabel));          
        }
```

VF page:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="span3">User Field:</label>
                        <apex:actionRegion >
                        <apex:selectList required="true" styleclass="span6 required" size="1" value="{!psc.Field__c}">
                            <apex:selectOptions value="{!userOptions}"/>                            
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!decideInputType}" 
                                reRender="operatorPanelId" status="showLoading" oncomplete="applyDatePickers();"/>
                        </apex:selectList>
                        </apex:actionRegion>
                    </div>
```

Comment: I think posting more of your code would help. The picklist renders ok on the page?

Comment: what does the onChange reference? an actionFunction that calls the controller? Does the onchange go to a new VF page where the current user doesn't have privileges?

Comment: @MichaelGill It renders picklist fine. Action support calls the method.

Comment: The onchange causes several possible interactions any of which could be the source of your problem - 1) decideInputType controller action method, (2) applyDatePickers javascript that in turn might invoke another actionFunction or pull down other controller variables; (3) rerender operatorPanelId that also could pull down controller variables that in turn get populated from sobjects; (4) status=showLoading that also could be interacting with the controller (albeit , less likely). Use debug statements/ js console to see which of the four is where you are getting hung up

Comment: @crop1645, I checked with removing "reRender="operatorPanelId" status="showLoading" oncomplete="applyDatePickers();" from actionSupport, but no luck. To check wether onchange is culprit, I changed onchange to onclick but "Insufficient..." message still persistent on onclick too. I suspect, accessing Schema.SObjectField might be problem.
I tried commenting all code in decideInputType but no success.

Comment: @crop1645, I noticed, I get 500 (Server Error) error in JS console. Not sure why it is coming.

Comment: Keep using reductive steps -- build a simple page that just uses {!decideInputType} but not in the context of onchange. When you have stripped the problem down to its simplest form, then post the code if still stuck.  Don't overwhelm us with code not related to the problem. Apex should have full access to Schema.describe